# Obtener campos relacionado Django

Tags: django, sql

Buen dia como puedo traer los campos relacionado de otra tabla en django, por ejemplo tengo dos modelos Persona y Localidad ya que al realizar los queryset solo me trae la llaves, pero no me trae todo los campos de la tabla relacionada.

my codigo en mysql

```
('SELECT * FROM localidad inner join Persona on(localidad.idlocalidad=Persona.localidad_idlocalidad)'):

obj = Localidad.objects.get(pk=511)
obj.persona_set.all()
>>> <QuerySet [<Persona: Persona object>]>
```

yo quiero trae los otros campos, no solo la llave primaria, tales como telefono,edad y demas, pero solo puedo traer la que esta en retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes acceder al resto de los campos de la siguiente manera:

```
 obj = Localidad.objects.get(pk=511)
 personas = obj.persona_set.all()
 for persona in personas:
     print(persona.edad)
```